# select2 to redirect on click

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-select2

I am using the select 2 plugin to search for users. Everything is up an running an my jsons end up with: `[{"id":"1","text":"Alex Fagard (afagard) ID: 1"}]` .etc.

I am using the following code to build the select 2 interface:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#username-search').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
    },
    ajax: {
      url: "classes/search.class.php?sType=users",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function (term, page) {
        return {
          term: term
        };
      },
      results: function (data, page) {
        return { results: data };
      }
    }
  });
});
```

However I am stuck on how to make it so that when the admin selects a user (aka clicks on their dropdown area) the page redirects to `userview.php?id=1` where `1` is the id from the JSON array.

Search function if anyone is interested:

```
public function searchUsers($term = '') {
    if (isset($term)) {
        $term = parent::secure($term);
        $params = array( ':searchQ' => $term . '%' );
        $sql = "SELECT distinct username as suggest, user_id, name
                FROM login_users
                WHERE username LIKE :searchQ
                OR name LIKE :searchQ
                OR user_id LIKE :searchQ
                ORDER BY username
                LIMIT 0, 5";

        $stmt = parent::query($sql, $params);

        if ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {
            while($suggest = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $data[] = array(
                    'id' => $suggest['user_id'],
                    'text' => $suggest['name'] . ' (' . $suggest['suggest'] . ')' . ' ID: ' . $suggest['user_id'],
                );
            }
        } else {
            $data[] = array('id'=>'0', 'text'=>'No results found!');
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
        flush();
    }
}
$searchParam = new Search();

if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
    // we secure the term before running the search and querying the database
    $term = $_GET['term'];
    switch (isset($_GET['sType']) ? $_GET['sType'] : NULL) {
        case 'users':
            $searchParam->searchUsers($term);
        break;
        case 'levels':
            $searchParam->searchLevels($term);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came across the same question a year after posting this and googled something and ended up here forgetting I ever posted it in the first place.

Well found a solution:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "users.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    term: term,
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                return {results: data};
            }
        }
    });
    $("#search").on("select2:selecting", function(e) {
        window.location.href = 'user_edit.php?id=' +  e.val;
    });
});
</script>
```

Event name is `select2:selecting`

Comment: This helped me a bit to apply it in Slim2 and Twig. So the way it worked for me is: `var value = $("#projects").val();
                var url = "{{ urlFor('projects.edit',{id: value }) }}";
                window.location.href = url+value;`. Thx.

Comment: This worked after changing `e.val` to `e.params.data.id`

Comment: worked very well, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Version 4.0 +

Events are now in format: select2:selecting (instead of select2-selecting)

```
$("#search").on("select2:selecting", function(e) {
 window.location.href = 'user_edit.php?id=' +  e.val;
});
```